# SQLCMD returns only the first 256 characters of column

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('"%SQLCMD%" -E -S %Server% -d %DestDb% -h-1 -i GetResult.sql') do (
  SET Result=%%a
)
ECHO "%Result%"
```

%Result% is set to the first 256 characters of the actual result.

Is there a way I can get the entire output of the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLCMD limits variable length columns to 256 by default. The -y 0 parameter fixed this.

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('"%SQLCMD%" -E -S %Server% -d %DestDb% -y 0 -i GetResult.sql') do (
  SET Result=%%a
)
ECHO "%Result%"
```

-h and -y parameters are mutually exclusive, so -h-1 had to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the full output by using the `-y 0` --> `0- unlimited`, but beware that this might cause performance issue.

```
sqlcmd -e -s server_name -Q "your query" -y 0> op_file_path
```

Note: `-h` and `-y` are mutually exclusive