# MS SQL sqlcmd -o for output option only dumps part of the query data before the stream is cut off

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I increase the size of the output stream to include all of the data being dumped?

I'm trying to get a JSON dump of a table's contents. Only part of the file contents dumps and the rest is cut off and not captured. The data stream seams to be limited to a certain size before the dump cuts off.

```
sqlcmd -S R2DB.DEVCOM.COM -d preckrb -Q "select * from user FOR JSON AUTO;" -o c:\temp\Users.json
```

Using SQL Server v14.0.3456.xxx

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351673/1024832

Comment: Also you probably want `select (select * from user FOR JSON AUTO);` otherwise it will get split into multiple rows

Comment: The re-directing of output is definitely better.  For some reason, the output file has injected \r\n at certain intervals in the data. I have to clean those up before the JSON data is useful. Any way to eliminate the carriage returns & line feeds?

Comment: Did you read Charlieface's comment?

Comment: Charlieface - select (select * from user FOR JSON AUTO); works and is the easiest solution.